# scale html email signature for mobile

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I am trying to code a email signatures for my small company. I am not a trained developer, but I do have some knowledge in HTML and CSS.

My question is there a way to scale the signature for mobile? I know I am limited in this because all styling has to be inline. My code is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
<div style="font-family: 'Helvetica','Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; ">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-right: 10px;font-size:12pt; line-height: 16pt">
            <img src="http://info.dochalo.com/hubfs/Email_Signatures/doc-halo-logo_email_signature.jpg" style="width:150px;" alt="Doc Halo" border="0">
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left:10px; border-left: 3px solid #0094ba;font-size:9pt;line-height: 14pt; color:#000">
            <p style = "padding:0px;margin:0px;"><span style="color:#0094ba"><b>Patrick Williams</b></span> | Graphic Designer
            </p>
            <p style = "padding:0px;margin:0px;margin-bottom:0px"><span style="color:#0094ba"><b>E </b></span><a href="mailto: email@ssite.com;" style="color:#00487A">email@site.com</a></p>
            <p style = "padding:0px;margin:0px;margin-bottom:0px"><span style="color:#0094ba"><b>P</b></span> 555.555.5555 <span style="color:#0094ba"><b> W </b></span><a href="https://www.google.com/" style="color:#00487A">site.com</a>
            </p>

        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

If I can just scale the image, or use a different version that is smaller that works too.

Thanks,
P

Comment: you can't use external fonts or images like that. pretty much NO mail clients will load external resources without popping up big warning/permissions dialogs to the user.

Comment: @MarcB: Gmail does.

Comment: well, no surprise there. gmail will know that "googleapis.com" is safe. but not everyone uses gmail.

Comment: Actually, Gmail will load all external images.

Comment: What you can do, is set the image to be `width: 100%`, and limit the image to `max-width: xxx` where "xxx" is the maximum width you desire. It will keep the image small on desktops, and larger on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="font-family: 'Helvetica','Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; ">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
            <img src="http://info.dochalo.com/hubfs/Email_Signatures/doc-halo-logo_email_signature.jpg" width="150" style="width:100%; max-width: 150px;" alt="Doc Halo">
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left:10px; border-left: 3px solid #0094ba;font-size:9px;line-height: 14px; color:#0094ba; font-weight:bold; ">
            Patrick Williams <span style="color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">| Graphic Designer</span><br>
            E <a href="mailto: email@ssite.com;" style="color:#00487A; font-weight: normal;">email@site.com</a><br>
            P 555.555.5555 
            W <a href="https://www.google.com/" style="color:#00487A; font-weight:normal;">site.com</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Here, I edited it a little bit to fit most of the major Mail Clients.

Comment: Is there a way I can make the " E email@site.com" "P 555.555.555" "W site.com" break together when scaled? The reason I wanted to scale the image is because on mobile the line breaks are misaligned and the groupings don't match up with the corresponding data.

Comment: Sure is! just use &nbsp; instead of a regular Space in every place where you don't want a Break. Exp.:  "E&nbsp;email@site.com". The nbsp stands for Non-Breakting-SPace btw ;)

Comment: Also in order to not break the lines at all try to give the text a fixed width. Try to fit the whole text in 320px since that is the usual smallest width of narrow smartphones.